# Change Visual Studio html text font color

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Can I change the font color and background for the plain text in an HTML/Razor page in the Visual Studio editor?

```
<h1>Highlight this plain code</h1>
```

I've tried the "Plain Text" setting, but that changes EVERYTHING.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually the Plain Text option.  I changed the color for that and text within h1 blocks changed to it, along with all other plain text in the HTML.  Not sure what you mean by it changing everything, as it did not change color for HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

For VS 2017, go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors and select what you want to change from Display items (ex: the HTML element) and select the color